# Polynomial Interpolation - Bound on Error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, interpolation

Let the function $f(x) = \ln(x)$ be approximated by an interpoation polynomial of degree of 9 with 10 nodes uniformly distributed in the interval $[1,2]$. What bound can be placed on the error?

I've been trying to think over the problem for the past day, but i'm still not sure sure how I am supposed to do this problem.

Comment: How are you interpolating?

Answer (score 2):

On http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error I find the error expression of $$\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n{(x-x_i)}$$ In this case $f(x)=\ln x$ so $$f^{(n+1)}(x)=n! (-1)^{n}x^{-(n+1)}$$ We have $$|f^{(n+1)}(x)|<n!$$ and $$\prod_{i=0}^n{(x-x_i)}<1$$ So in this case an error bound is just $$\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}={1\over 10}$$

Comment: ah, makes sense!

Comment: @Ozera See this article: https://www.math.okstate.edu/~binegar/4513-F98/4513-l16.pdf It gives a good explanation of that formula.

Comment: Sorry for digging an old post back up, but your second centred line of math should read $f^{n+1}(x) = (n)!*(-1)^n*x^{-(n+1)}$, no? This factor of $9!$ greatly changes the error bound.

Comment: @Alex Yes thanks.